# Ansible - Combine key:values from lists of dicts

Tags: dictionary, ansible, comparison

I've two data structures, each a list of dictionaries.

```
"ldap_identity_sources": [
    {
        "_create_time": 1676110324694,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1676110742884,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=apac,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "id": "831a1a64-xyz1-2b12-813d-12358ce0b237",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16Apac02.apac.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    },
    {
        "_create_time": 1679110539836,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1667677961879,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=emea,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "emea.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "emea.adme.com",
        "id": "9af347b8-123a-bcd4-958e-abcdefg0060",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16emea01.emea.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    }
    ]
```

and

```
"server_cert": [
    {
        "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nBOGUS_CERT_DATA\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
        "ldap_server": "DCS16APAC02.apac.acme.com"
    }
    ]
```

I need to add the certificate from "server_cert" into "ldap_identity_sources" by checking to see if the value of server_cert.ldap_server is in the value of "ldap_identity_sources.0.ldap_servers.0.url

That is, is DCS16APAC02.apac.acme.com in LDAP://DCS16Apac02.apac.acme.com:3268

I've tried the following

```
- name: add Certificate to ldap_identity_sources by comparing values
  set_fact:
    ldap_identity_sources_new: "{{ ldap_identity_sources + [{ 'cert': item.cert }] }}"
  with_items: "{{server_cert}}"
  when: item.ldap_server in ldap_identity_sources.0.ldap_servers.0.url
```

The above fails with "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"

---

Thanks for the below answers but, they are not quite what i'm looking for. That said, they have been helpful in getting closer to what i want.

```
- name: Add LDAP Servername to ldap_identity_sources
  vars:
    ldap_servername: "{{ item | combine({ 'ldap_servername': item.ldap_servers.0.url[7:-5]|lower }) }}"
  loop: "{{ldap_identity_sources}}"
  set_fact:
    ldap_identity_sources_with_servername: "{{ ldap_identity_sources_with_servername | d([]) + [ldap_servername] }}"
```

gives

```
"ldap_identity_sources_with_servername": [
    {
        "_create_time": 1676110324694,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1676110742884,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=apac,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "id": "831a1a64-xyz1-2b12-813d-12358ce0b237",
        "ldap_servername": "dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16Apac02.apac.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    },
    {
        "_create_time": 1679110539836,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1667677961879,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=emea,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "emea.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "emea.adme.com",
        "id": "9af347b8-123a-bcd4-958e-abcdefg0060",
        "ldap_servername": "dcs16emea01.emea.acme.com",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16emea01.emea.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    }
]
```

I then convert the server_cert_list to a dict and then to lowercase

```
- name: convert server_cert_list to a dictionary
  set_fact:
    server_cert_dict: "{{ server_cert_list | items2dict( key_name='ldap_server', value_name='cert' ) }}"

- name:  Convert the server_cert_dict keys to lower-case
  set_fact:
    server_cert_lower: "{{ dict( server_cert_dict.keys()|map('lower') | zip( server_cert_dict.values() ) ) }}"
```

That gives

```
"server_cert_lower": {
    "dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----BOGUS_CERT_DATA-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
    "dcs16emea01.emea.acme.com": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----BOGUS_CERT_DATA-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
```

I still need to add the certificate for each server into the list of dicts *ldap_identity_sources_with_servername*

Now that *ldap_identity_sources_with_servername* has a key:value for *ldap_servername* and, *server_cert_lower* has a key for the servername, i think i'm a step closer to combining the two.

```
- name: Use Jinja2 to create needed data structure
  set_fact: 
    result_str: |
      {% for e in ldap_identity_sources_with_servername %}
      {{ e }}:
      {% for k,v in e.items() %}
      {% if k in server_cert_lower.keys() %}
        - "ldap_cert": {{server_cert_lower[k]}}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It skips because your `server_cert` and both urls in `ldap_identity_sources` are different. So, none of the them match. If your objective is to match the first url then check the `APAC02` vs `Apac02`.

Comment: It's not worth the effort to update the lists of dictionaries inside a list. Your two lists should be fine. See my answer on how to iterate the list and substitute the certificates. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, combining help from comments provided here and a suggestion from a colleague.

First, as before, add the servername to the list of Identity Sources. This time, make sure the servername is lowercase

```
- name: Add LDAP Servername to ldap_identity_sources
  vars:
    ldap_servername: "{{ item | combine({ 'ldap_server': item.ldap_servers.0.url[7:-5]|lower }) }}"
  loop: "{{ldap_identity_sources}}"
  set_fact:
    ldap_identity_sources_with_servername: "{{ ldap_identity_sources_with_servername | d([]) + [ldap_servername] }}"
```

That gives

```
"ldap_identity_sources": [
    {
        "_create_time": 1676110324694,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1676110742884,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=apac,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "id": "831a1a64-xyz1-2b12-813d-12358ce0b237",
        "ldap_server": "dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16Apac02.apac.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    },
    {
        "_create_time": 1679110539836,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1667677961879,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=emea,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "emea.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "emea.acme.com",
        "id": "9af347b8-123a-bcd4-958e-abcdefg0060",
        "ldap_server": "dcs16emea01.emea.acme.com",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16emea01.emea.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    }
]
```

As before, pair the servername with it's certificate

```
- name: Set fact to pair LDAP Server with its Certificate
  set_fact:
    server_cert_list: "{{ server_cert_list|d([]) + [{'ldap_server': item.json.details.0.subject_cn|lower, 'cert': item.json.pem_encoded }] }}"
  with_items: "{{ cert_facts.results }}"
```

This gives

```
"server_cert_list": {
    "dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----BOGUS_CERT_DATA-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
    "dcs16emea01.emea.acme.com": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----BOGUS_CERT_DATA-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
```

Now the solution

```
- name: Add LDAP Certificate to ldap_identity_sources_with_servername
  set_fact:
    merged: "{{ merged|d([]) + [dict(item.0, **item.1)] }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ ldap_identity_sources_with_servername }}"
    - "{{ server_cert_list }}"
  when: item.0.ldap_server == item.1.ldap_server

- name: print merged 
  debug:
    msg: "{{merged}}"
```

that gives

```
"merged": [
    {
        "_create_time": 1676110324694,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1676110742884,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=apac,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "apac.acme.com",
        "id": "831a1a64-xyz1-2b12-813d-12358ce0b237",
        "ldap_server": "dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com",
        "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----BOGUS_CERT_DATA-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16Apac02.apac.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    },
    {
        "_create_time": 1679110539836,
        "_create_user": "admin",
        "_last_modified_time": 1667677961879,
        "_last_modified_user": "admin",
        "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
        "_revision": 1,
        "_system_owned": false,
        "base_dn": "dc=emea,dc=acme,dc=com",
        "display_name": "emea.acme.com",
        "domain_name": "emea.acme.com",
        "id": "9af347b8-123a-bcd4-958e-abcdefg0060",
        "ldap_server": "dcs16emea01.emea.acme.com",
        "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----BOGUS_CERT_DATA-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
        "ldap_servers": [
            {
                "bind_identity": "svc_account_name@amer.acme.com",
                "enabled": true,
                "url": "LDAP://DCS16emea01.emea.acme.com:3268",
                "use_starttls": false
            }
        ],
        "resource_type": "ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource"
    }
]
```

Comment: The certificates belong to the LDAP servers. The attribute *ldap_servers* is a  list. There might be more items on the list. Hence, you should put *cert* into the items of *ldap_servers*.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBotka, i've been trying to edit 

- name: Add LDAP Certificate to ldap_identity_sources_with_servername
  set_fact:
    merged: "{{ merged|d([]) + [dict(item.0, **item.1)] }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ ldap_identity_sources_with_servername }}"
    - "{{ server_cert_list }}"
  when: item.0.ldap_svr == item.1.ldap_svr


so that the certificate is added to the _ldap_servers_ attribute but have not had any success. Could you please advise on this

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, convert the list *server_cert* to a dictionary and convert the keys to lower-case

```yaml
  server_cert_dict: "{{ server_cert|
                        items2dict(key_name='ldap_server',
                                   value_name='cert') }}"
  server_cert_lower: "{{ dict(server_cert_dict.keys()|map('lower')|
                              zip(server_cert_dict.values())) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  server_cert_lower:
    dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com: |-
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      BOGUS_CERT_DATA
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Iterate the list *ldap_identity_sources* with the subelements *ldap_servers* and use the dictionary *server_cert_lower* to get the certificates

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ server_cert_lower[url_lower]|d('') }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ldap_identity_sources }}"
        - ldap_servers
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.domain_name }} - {{ url_lower }}"
      vars:
        url_lower: "{{ item.1.url[7:-5]|lower }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=apac.acme.com - dcs16apac02.apac.acme.com) => 
  msg: |-
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    BOGUS_CERT_DATA
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
ok: [localhost] => (item=emea.adme.com - dcs16emea01.emea.dell.com) => 
  msg: ''
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    server_cert:
      - cert: |-
          -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
          BOGUS_CERT_DATA
          -----END CERTIFICATE-----
        ldap_server: DCS16APAC02.apac.acme.com

    ldap_identity_sources:
      - _create_time: 1676110324694
        _create_user: admin
        _last_modified_time: 1676110742884
        _last_modified_user: admin
        _protection: NOT_PROTECTED
        _revision: 1
        _system_owned: false
        base_dn: dc=apac,dc=acme,dc=com
        display_name: apac.acme.com
        domain_name: apac.acme.com
        id: 831a1a64-xyz1-2b12-813d-12358ce0b237
        ldap_servers:
        - bind_identity: svc_account_name@amer.acme.com
          enabled: true
          url: LDAP://DCS16Apac02.apac.acme.com:3268
          use_starttls: false
        resource_type: ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource
      - _create_time: 1679110539836
        _create_user: admin
        _last_modified_time: 1667677961879
        _last_modified_user: admin
        _protection: NOT_PROTECTED
        _revision: 1
        _system_owned: false
        base_dn: dc=emea,dc=acme,dc=com
        display_name: emea.acme.com
        domain_name: emea.adme.com
        id: 9af347b8-123a-bcd4-958e-abcdefg0060
        ldap_servers:
        - bind_identity: svc_account_name@amer.acme.com
          enabled: true
          url: LDAP://DCS16emea01.emea.dell.com:3268
          use_starttls: false
        resource_type: ActiveDirectoryIdentitySource

    server_cert_dict: "{{ server_cert|
                          items2dict(key_name='ldap_server',
                                     value_name='cert') }}"
    server_cert_lower: "{{ dict(server_cert_dict.keys()|map('lower')|
                                zip(server_cert_dict.values())) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: server_cert_dict
    - debug:
        var: server_cert_lower

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ server_cert_lower[url_lower]|d('') }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ldap_identity_sources }}"
        - ldap_servers
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.domain_name }} - {{ url_lower }}"
      vars:
        url_lower: "{{ item.1.url[7:-5]|lower }}"
```